# Mutt: sending html-formatted e-mail with an attachment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, mutt

I have a requirement like, i need to export the sql query result set to a .csv file and send it as an attachment. but here i need to include the body with html formatting and wanted to include sample rows of the .csv file in body as well in html format.

csv file contains :

Id    ID_CNT
a      3
b      6

and i want to display the mail body with sample rows.

I have tried below two ways

```
mutt -e "set content_type=text/html"  -a query_gen23.csv -s "abc" abc@gmail.com 

export CONTENT="test.html"
export SUBJECT="$subject"
#(
# echo "To: "
# echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
# echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
# echo "Content-Type: text/html"
# echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
# cat $CONTENT
#) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
mutt -s "$subject" -a "$subject".csv -a test.html "$MAILTO" </dev/null
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free service to get your code/scripts etc. written/implemented. Please present your attempts/code snippets or whatever you've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since I had used mutt, but if I remember right, it expects the body of the mail from standard input. In your script, you input-redirect from /dev/null !

I would divide the task into two steps: One creates the body (HTML code with the CSV sample lines), and the second step pipes this file into mutt. I think this is much easier than trying to do everything at once.

Comment: can u help me on how to create the body and csv samples. which ever the  ways i tried i failed all those.

Comment: You need to be more concrete. Where exactly do you have problems with it? After all, you just need to create a HTML file and insert the samples into it.

Comment: Yes. that's what exactly i need

Comment: And where exactly is your problem? I guess your problem is not that you do not know how to create a file .....

Answer (score -1):

Following works fine for me :

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

export MAILTO="spam@ebay.com"
export SUBJECT="Mail Subject"
export BODY="/tmp/email_body.html"
export ATTACH="/tmp/attachment.txt"
(
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-q1w2e3r4t5"'
 echo
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat $BODY
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
 echo 'Content-Type: application; name="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 uuencode -m $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH)
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5--'
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
```